# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, jaxb2, weblogic11g

I am troubling with classloading issue on weblogic 10.3.6 on classnotfound exception regarding `org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl`.
Tried to put  `<wls:package-name>org.apache.xerces.*</wls:package-name>` in `weblogic-application.xml`. Made sure that `xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar` is placed at root of ear, but weblogic ignores this fact :(
`XMLGregorianCalendarImpl` is apparently used in `XMLStreamReader` functionality.

```
    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeClass);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    final XMLStreamReader xmlr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(reader);
```

How to make weblogic accept the filtering approach?
The application has apache cxf and jaxws webservices.
Im stuck, plz help :(
See whole stacktrace here:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/jaxp/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendarImpl
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:408)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$4.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:288)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$4.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:290)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:247)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:515)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:339)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:217)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:186)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:368)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:347)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.common.util.LargeXmlFileProcessorHandler.process(LargeXmlFileProcessorHandler.java:83)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.common.util.LargeXmlFileProcessorHandler.validate(LargeXmlFileProcessorHandler.java:38)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.bum.processor.BumFTPFileProcessor.downloadFileAndSave(BumFTPFileProcessor.java:102)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.bum.processor.BumFTPFileProcessor.process(BumFTPFileProcessor.java:91)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.bum.processor.BumFTPFileProcessor.process(BumFTPFileProcessor.java:35)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.common.integration.FTPClientManager.handleFiles(FTPClientManager.java:142)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.bum.job.BumHentFraUdbetalingDkWorkerExecutorImpl.doWork(BumHentFraUdbetalingDkWorkerExecutorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1828.doWork(Unknown Source)
        at dk.skat.efi.wls.bebb.scheduler.BumHentFraUdbetalingDkTaskImpl.execute(BumHentFraUdbetalingDkTaskImpl.java:35)
        at dk.skat.efi.common.scheduling.AbstractScheduledTask.execute(AbstractScheduledTask.java:320)
        at dk.skat.efi.common.scheduling.AbstractScheduledTask$PrivilegedTaskAction$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(AbstractScheduledTask.java:253)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:34)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at dk.skat.efi.common.scheduling.AbstractScheduledTask$PrivilegedTaskAction.run(AbstractScheduledTask.java:251)
        at dk.skat.efi.common.scheduling.AbstractScheduledTask$PrivilegedTaskAction.run(AbstractScheduledTask.java:235)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire `weblogic-application.xml` section?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround. The application is using xmlbeans and now jaxb. Created a DateAdapter and inherited from XMLAdapter specifying the how date should be marshalled. Then added it to my xjb configuration.

```
public class XmlToDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    public static final DateFormat SKAT_DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    @Override
        public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        Date date = SKAT_DATE_FORMATTER.parse(v);
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        return SKAT_DATE_FORMATTER.format(v);
    }

}
```

Comment: kudos for answering your own question. I'm currently having problems with this myself